# Handling StatusCodes when Entities which do not exist but are not part of the resource either?

Tags: api, asp.net-core-webapi, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes, http-status-code-400

Lets say i have a Book API with following endpoint:

```
PUT /api/Book/{bookId}/Author/{authorId}/?userId={userId}
```

(the userId is the User who adds/removes the author from the book)
Which status codes would you return if one of those entities does not exist?

I am currently playing around with Mediatr in an .NET Core 7 API.
I throw BadRequest- and NotFound-Exceptions in my CommandHandlers and handle them in a MiddleWare, mapping those Exceptions to StatusCodes.
I don't really like this approach, because my BusinessLogic decides about the returning StatusCode but does not know anything about the request.

Maybe i am thinking too much about this and better return 404s for anything that was not found?

Comment: “Which status codes would you return if one of those entities does not exist?” Use Status code 200, 400 and 404 are fine, depending on your preference. In my opinion, I prefer to use 400 status code and ModelState validation error.